# Is there a VIM plugin that will show available functions from a class object in PHP?

Tags: php, vim, plugins

for instance, say I create an object.

$myobject = new MyClass;

when I type $myobject->[I'd like a menu to pop up here with available functions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP omni-completion of Vim 7 should do that.

```
:help ft-php-omni
:help new-omni-completion
```

Comment: Please excuse my newbiness, but how would I go about installing that for php?

Comment: At first you have to install ctags. A good one is exuberant ctags, see http://ctags.sourceforge.net/. Use this tool to create a tags file of your PHP source code.
Then let Vim's "tags" variable point to that tags file
  :set tags=~/.vim/mytags.tags
Perhaps these links give further hints:
 http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/164-Vim-Productivity-Tips-for-PHP-Developers.html
  http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/134-exuberant-ctags-with-PHP-in-Vim.html